# How can I create a CustomEvent with detail object in Fable?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

In Javascript it is possible to create a `CustomEvent` and include a second argument containing detail data to pass when the event is dispatched. For example:

```
let evt = new CustomEvent("hello", {
    detail: { name: "John" }
  });
elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

With Fable I can create a CustomEvent without the detail data as follows:

```
let evt = CustomEvent.Create "hello"
elem.dispatchEvent evt
```

The definition in [Browser.Events](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-browser/blob/master/src/Event/Browser.Event.fs) is as follows:

```
type [<AllowNullLiteral>] CustomEventType =
    [<Emit("new $0($1...)")>] abstract Create : typeArg: string * ?eventInitDict: CustomEventInit -> CustomEvent
    [<Emit("new $0($1...)")>] abstract Create : typeArg: string * ?eventInitDict: CustomEventInit<'T> -> CustomEvent<'T>
```

But I can't work out how to create a CustomEventInit as I think this is an interface.

```
let details:CustomEventInit = { detail = {name = "John"}} //ERROR: This type is not a record type
let evt = CustomEvent.Create ("hello", details)
elem.dispatchEvent evt
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomEventInit` is a class type, so you can instantiate it using an object expression:

```ml
let details =
    let mutable bubbles = true
    let mutable cancelable = true
    let mutable composed = true
    let mutable detail : obj = "John"
    {
        new CustomEventInit with
            member _.bubbles
                with set(value) = bubbles <- value
                and get() = bubbles
            member _.cancelable
                with set(value) = cancelable <- value
                and get() = cancelable
            member _.composed
                with set(value) = bubbles <- value
                and get() = bubbles
            member _.detail
                with set(value) = detail <- value
                and get() = detail
    }
```

Or you could create a named subclass if you prefer.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you that has got me unblocked. I'm surprised by the amount of boilerplate needed, I thought something like the `CustomEvent.Create` helper function would have been provided in Fable. I had got stuck on wanting to call something like `CustomeEventInit.Create`